# Server closes bot connection by itself

Tags: c#, debian, bots, discord.net

I recently moved my C# .NET Core bot to VPS on Debian 10 and when i tried to start the bot it gave me this exception

```
 ---> Discord.Net.WebSocketClosedException: The server sent close 1000: ""
   at Discord.Net.WebSockets.DefaultWebSocketClient.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Discord.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<<StartAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

It worked perfectly on previous server and on my laptop. Now it disconnects without reconnection after it informs about servers' connections. What could i miss? Something in code or server setup?

Comment: so long as it reconnects/resumes you're fine. There is nothing in your setup that would cause or prevent this.

Comment: @Anu6is the problem is that it doesn't reconnect, just stuck after disconnection messages

Comment: then use the nightly build, it should mange resuming sessions better.